# I want to filter data using AJAX in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

This controller is giving the value even the field are empty. I want to pop msg if all the field are empty.

```
Controller
public function filterSearch(Request $request){

    $obj = (new VaccinationInfo)->newQuery(); 

    if($request->has('name')){
        $name = request('name');
        $obj->where('vaccination_name', '=', $name);
    }

    if($request->has('duration_from')){
        $duration_from = request('duration_from');
        $obj->where('actual_date', '=', $duration_from);

    }
    if($request->has('duration_to')){
        $duration_to = request('duration_to');
        $obj->where('vaccination_date', '=', $duration_to);

    }
    $search = $obj->get();
```

So I have issue in filtering the data from any one of the field. But if I fill all the field in form it will filter.

Comment: Where is your form blade? where is your ajax ? please give us the information to help you.

Comment: @Jovs I have uploaded the ajax and blade file image at top heading

Comment: are you sure you want `=` not `LIKE` ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
public function filterSearch(Request $request){

$obj = (new VaccinationInfo)->newQuery(); 

if($request->has('name')){
    $name = request('name');
    $obj = $obj->where('vaccination_name', '=', $name);
}

if($request->has('duration_from')){
    $duration_from = request('duration_from');
    $obj = $obj->where('actual_date', '=', $duration_from);

}
if($request->has('duration_to')){
    $duration_to = request('duration_to');
    $obj = $obj->where('vaccination_date', '=', $duration_to);

}
$search = $obj->get();
```

Comment: hey Anmup Giri with that code i can't filter from particular one